# How to pull information out of the middle of a cell?

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a couple thousand rows of data that I am trying to pull certain bits of information from and place into their own cell.

I have a column of data that looks something like this:

`1@48x50x38
2@50x29x48
1@68x29x58
1@50x21x68`

The first number is the quantity which I can easily pull out with a LEFT formula.  I also need to pull out the other sets of numbers to be placed in their own cell, but have no idea how to pull those numbers out from the middle of the string.

I would like for it to look like this.

`A             B           C             D
1             48          50            38
2             50          29            48
1             68          29            58
1             50          21            68`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the cells you want to parse and run this small macro:

```
Sub convertt()
    For Each r In Selection
        V = r.Value
        If V <> "" Then
            ary = Split(V, "@")
            bry = Split(ary(1), "x")
            r.Value = ary(0)
            r.Offset(0, 1) = bry(0)
            r.Offset(0, 2) = bry(1)
            r.Offset(0, 3) = bry(2)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

This version will not be case sensitive:

```
Sub convertt()
    For Each r In Selection
        V = r.Value
        If V <> "" Then
            ary = Split(V, "@")
            bry = Split(LCase(ary(1)), "x")
            r.Value = ary(0)
            r.Offset(0, 1) = bry(0)
            r.Offset(0, 2) = bry(1)
            r.Offset(0, 3) = bry(2)
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: It's very possible that I screwed something up, but when I run this macro I get a run-time error '9' stating "subscript out of range".  When I select the Debug option it highlights the "r.Offset(0, 2) = bry(1)" section of the macro.

Comment: That can happen if one of the **Selected** cells does not have a pair of *lower-case* **x's**

Comment: Bingo!  I wasn't aware that the macro was case sensitive.  There are instances where the x is upper-case.  The macro worked beautifully up until it stumbled upon one of these and crashed.

Comment: You, sir, are my hero.  Maybe one day I will take the time to break that down and figure out exactly what you did.  You have saved me a ton of time.  Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

The `MID` function can be used to extract an arbitrary part of the string using a start and length values.
However I suspect your question is how do you locate the start and length values.

The `FIND` function will provide this so you will use this as a parameter to MID

So, to get the first number after the @ symbol you would use (assuming cell is C8):

```
=MID(C8,FIND("@", C8)+1,FIND("x",C8)-FIND("@", C8)-1)
```

The other mid number can be extracted as follows:

```
=MID(C8,FIND("x", C8)+1,FIND("x",C8,FIND("x",C8)+1)-FIND("x", C8)-1)
```

The first and last numbers can use the `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions as you mentioned.

Final number:

```
=RIGHT(C8,LEN(C8)-FIND("x",C8,FIND("x",C8)+1))
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, sir.  I appreciate you taking the time to offer a solution as well.  Thank you very much.